# Windows 10: Tool Window Title Bar is Too High

Tags: windows-10, notepad++

I've tested some custom Windows 10 themes, and returned now to Windows default theme.

Notepad++ Search dialog's title (a tool window) has become higher and its Close button is not vertically centered.

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?
Building Notepad++ without the "WS_THICKFRAME" style, I get a normal height title. What should I look for in the Registry?

Thank you.

Comment: Ask Notepad++ developpers.

Comment: @Toto, no. This looks to be a scaling issue in Windows, it's nothing to do with Notepad++. The application is just calling a .Net Framework/C++ standard dialog box with customized layout.

Comment: @spikey_richie, You're absolutely right. Thanks.

Comment: That is how tool windows appear. Using https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/04/this-uses-inbuilt-compilers-in-windows.html to hide Notepad from taskbar by setting it as a tool window it looks the same.

Comment: A tool window is not a dialog window - *WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
Creates a tool window; that is, a window intended to be used as a floating toolbar. A tool window has a title bar that is shorter than a normal title bar, and the window title is drawn using a smaller font. A tool window does not appear in the taskbar or in the dialog that appears when the user presses ALT+TAB. If a tool window has a system menu, its icon is not displayed on the title bar. However, you can display the system menu by right-clicking or by typing ALT+SPACE. *

Comment: @user1292580, that tool window's title bar was shorter before some theme probably messed something in the Registry. Thank you.

Comment: It looks absolutely correct. That is what tool windows look like.

Comment: Do you mean the Close button is NOT vertically centered? Can you please set PaddedBorderWidth under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics to 0 (sign out and in) and see if there's any change? Thank you.

Comment: Tool windows don't have vertically centred close buttons..

Comment: Thanks for confirming.